# CiviCRM 5.13.1 is not showing "Added By" coumn value

Tags: drupal, activities

I upgraded site Drupal 7.66 + CiviCRM with latest version 5.13.1 and found out that if you go to any user profile and click on Activities tab then you can see there is "n/a" in "Added by" Column.
[image]

But when I click on "View" activity link then I can able to see "Added by" value.
[image]

It was working with last version 5.10.4, I think this is bug in CiviCRM latest version.
Any help is really appreciate.

Created issue civicrm lab
https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/951

Comment: This has previously been reported here: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/942 If you could help by testing the patch linked there and provide your comments on the ticket that would help get it fixed.

Comment: thank you @Aidan

Comment: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/942 patch is working.

Comment: Great - please add your comments on https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/14218

Answer (score 3):

I'm marking this question as now being answered.  The problem is resolved by upgrading from civicrm version 5.13.1 to 5.13.4